# PHP, MySQL, jQuery, AJAX: json data returns correct response but frontend returns error

Tags: php, mysql, json, jquery

I have a user registration form. I am doing server side validation on the fly via AJAX. The quick summary of my problem is that upon validating 2 fields, I get error for the second field validation. If I comment first field, then the 2nd field does not show any error. It has this weird behavior. More details below:

The HTML, JS and Php code are below:

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form id="SignupForm" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Free Signup</legend>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" /><span id="status_username"></span>
        <br />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" /><span id="status_email"></span>
        <br />
        <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email</label>
        <input name="confirm_email" type="text" id="confirm_email" /><span id="status_confirm_email"></span>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input id="sbt" type="button" value="Submit form" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#email").blur(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var msgbox2 = $("#status_email");
    if (email.length > 3) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check_ajax2.php',
        data: "email=" + email,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.success == 'y') {
            alert('Available');
          } else {
            alert('Not Available');
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#confirm_email").blur(function() {
    var confirm_email = $("#confirm_email").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var msgbox3 = $("#status_confirm_email");

    if (confirm_email.length > 3) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check_ajax2.php',
        data: 'confirm_email=' + confirm_email + '&email=' + email,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.success == 'y') {
            alert('Available');
          } else {
            alert('Not Available');
          }
        },
        error: function(data) {
          alert('Some error');
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php //check_ajax2.php


if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];


    $res = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE email = '$email' ");
    $i_exists = mysql_num_rows($res);

    if( 0 == $i_exists )
    {
        $success = 'y';
        $msg_email = 'Email available';
    }
    else
    {
        $success = 'n';
        $msg_email = 'Email is already in use.</font>';
    }

    print json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'msg_email' => $msg_email)); 
}

if(isset($_POST['confirm_email']))
{
    $confirm_email = $_POST['confirm_email'];
    $email = ( isset($_POST['email']) && trim($_POST['email']) != '' ? $_POST['email'] : '' );



    $res = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE email = '$confirm_email' ");
    $i_exists = mysql_num_rows($res);


    if( 0 == $i_exists ) 
    {
        if( isset($email) && isset($confirm_email) &&  $email == $confirm_email )
        {
            $success = 'y';
            $msg_confirm_email = 'Email available and match';
        }
        else
        {
            $success = 'n';
            $msg_confirm_email = 'Email and Confirm Email do NOT match.';
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        $success = 'n';
        $msg_confirm_email = 'Email already exists.';
    }

    print json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'msg_confirm_email' => $msg_confirm_email)); 
}

?>
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

As long as I am validating the `$_POST['email']` as well as `$_POST['confirm_email']` in the check_ajax2.php file, the validation for confirm_email field always returns an error. With my limited knowledge of Firebug, however, I did find out that the following were the responses when I entered email and confirm_email in the fields:

**RESPONSE 1:**
{"success":"y","msg_email":"Email available"}

**RESPONSE 2:**
{"success":"y","msg_email":"Email available"}{"success":"n","msg_confirm_email":"Email and Confirm Email do NOT match."}

Although the RESPONSE 2 shows that we are receiving the correct message via msg_confirm_email, in the front end, the alert 'Some error' is popping up (I have enabled the alert for debugging). I have spent 48 hours trying to change every part of the code wherever possible, but with only little success. What is weird about this is that if I comment the validation for `$_POST['email']` field completely, then the validation for `$_POST['confirm_email']` field is displaying correctly without any errors. If I enable it back, it is validating email field correctly, but when it reaches the point of validating confirm_email field, it is again showing me the error.

I have also tried renaming success variable in check_ajax2.php page to other different names for both `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['confirm_email']` but no success. I will be adding more fields in the form and validating within the check_ajax2.php page. So I am not planning on using different ajax pages for validating each of those fields (and I don't think it's smart to do it that way). I am not a jquery or AJAX guru, so all help in resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error handler is called if the HTTP status code is indicative of an error as well as when parsing of the response fails.

I think that your error handler is being called upon receipt of RESPONSE 2 because `{"success":"y","msg_email":"Email available"}{"success":"n","msg_confirm_email":"Email and Confirm Email do NOT match."}` is not valid JSON. You can use the validator at: http://jsonlint.com/.

In your PHP, you could define a `$response_object` array at the top and print `json_encode($response_object)` at the bottom:

```
<?php //check_ajax2.php

$response_object = array('success' => 'y');

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];


    $res = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($email)  . "' ");
    $i_exists = mysql_num_rows($res);

    if( 0 == $i_exists )
    {
        $msg_email = 'Email available';
    }
    else
    {
        $response_object['success'] = 'n';
        $msg_email = 'Email is already in use.';
    }

    $response_object['msg_email'] = $msg_email; 
}

if(isset($_POST['confirm_email']))
{
    $confirm_email = $_POST['confirm_email'];
    $email = ( isset($_POST['email']) && trim($_POST['email']) != '' ? $_POST['email'] : '' );



    $res = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($confirm_email) . "' ");
    $i_exists = mysql_num_rows($res);


    if( 0 == $i_exists ) 
    {
        if( isset($email) && isset($confirm_email) &&  $email == $confirm_email )
        {
            $msg_confirm_email = 'Email available and match';
        }
        else
        {
            $response_object['success'] = 'n';
            $msg_confirm_email = 'Email and Confirm Email do NOT match.';
        }      
    }
    else
    {
        $response_object['success'] = 'n';
        $msg_confirm_email = 'Email already exists.';
    }

    $response_object['msg_confirm_email'] = $msg_confirm_email; 
}

print json_encode($response_object);
```

Note that I added calls to `mysql_real_escape_string` to help prevent SQL injection.

Comment: +1. Thank you so much for the solution, Daniel. It worked like a charm. Also I tried out the link that you gave me for validating the json response but when I hit the validate button, it's giving me the results as Parsing failed. I gave it an input of {"success":"y","msg_email":"Email available"}{"success":"n","msg_confirm_email":"Email and Confirm Email do NOT match."} .Did I do the right thing? Sorry, I am a total newbie to the link that you gave me and hence the question.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Yes, you are doing the right thing. It says "Parsing failed" because the string `{"success":"y","msg_email":"Email available"}{"success":"n","msg_confirm_email":"Email and Confirm Email do NOT match."}` is not valid JSON. Basically, if the jsonlint website says "Parsing failed", then you know that jQuery will call your error handler.

Comment: Thanks much for taking time to explain it. Appreciate it. Also I was just wondering if you know any methods that I can use to shorten the php error checking code for the individual fields? What I mean by this is that currently for each field that I need to validate, I am going to have to add corresponding code in JS and PHP processing. So is there any way that I can keep the code simple both in JS (preferred) & PHP to validate these without having to write code for each of them separately? Please let me know if there's any.It's too much trouble already to type individual code & error checking!

Comment: Yes. PHP frameworks can help you to reduce the amount of validation code that you have to write. There are a couple of PHP frameworks that I would recommend investing the time to learn: CakePHP when your website is heavily database-driven (CRUD: Create, Read, Update and Delete) and CodeIgniter for an all-around good framework. It takes some time to learn them and set them up, but the benefits of a framework can be well worth the time invested, even if you only use a few of the features. See, for example, http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very much for the link. PHP validation is somewhat manageable while it is JS validation that I am trying to really sort out. Are any links that may reference to shortening JS validation code available?

Comment: Since you are using patterns such as `msg_email` for the <input> with name `email`, `msg_username` for the <input> with name `username`, etc., I would iterate through the form, examining all <input>s and <select>s, and try to find a value in the response that was "msg_" concatenated with the field's `name`. If found, then attempt to find the <span> with id "status_" + field name to set its `innerHTML` using jQuery's `html`. Right now, you are not doing client-side validation, but if you decide to do this, then try implementing the framework's validation routines in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I shall try that.

Comment: Thanks @DanielTrebbien, I have been banging my head against a wall for about 10 hours a day for almost a week on a problem and your answer, together with the JSON validator you linked, did it. I wish I had come across your answer about a week ago! +1 +1